# Numpy: apply function that creates an array

Tags: numpy

Numpy apply_along_axis/apply_over_axes assume that the applied function returns a scalar, but what if I want to use a function that returns an array (thus adding new dimensions)?

Below is a simplified example. I want to apply my_func to each row of an array. I could do this in pandas but expect numpy to be faster.
Function:

```
def my_func(k):
    x = np.arange(3)
    y = x ** k
    return y
```

Original array:

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Expected result:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  4,  9],
       [ 0,  1,  8, 27]], dtype=int32)
```

**Update**: it was an oversimplified example. I should have said the real function can only take a scalar as input. But the solution proposed by Michael Szczesny in comments works for such functions too.

**Update2**: I should have said a function that does not broadcast, like this:

```
def my_func(k):
    return np.random.randint(1, 4, 5) + k
```

Comment: is the original array the input for the function `my_func`?

Comment: Is `k ** x` not working ?

Comment: Arihant, yes, I want to apply my_func to the original array, i.e. I take its argument k from the original array.

Comment: Psidom, it is a simplified example just to see if it is possible in principle. I have a more complex function.

Comment: if you can pass the entire array, won't that solve your problem? and try increasing the `x` value -> `x = np.arange(4)`

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis(my_func, 1, data)` **does** work for the included example.

Comment: Airhant, sorry, I have little experience with numpy and oversimplified the example. I overlooked the fact that my real function can only take scalars. Solution proposed by Michael works for such functions too.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is designed to work with a function that takes a 1d array as argument, not one that takes a scalar.  And speedwise, it is not an improvement for plain python iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I am sharing the code for your reference,

```
import numpy as np
def my_func(k):
    x = np.arange(4)
    y = x ** k
    return y
inp = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
print(my_func(inp))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 0  1  4  9]
 [ 0  1  8 27]]
```

See if it helps?

Comment: This is a very neat solution for functions that can take arrays as input.

Answer (score 1):

Your function, with an added `print` to see exactly what `k` is:

```
In [39]: def my_func(k):
    ...:     print(k)
    ...:     x = np.arange(4)     # range to match your expected result
    ...:     y = x ** k
    ...:     return y
    ...:
```

As written the function works with your (3,1) array, `arr = np.arange(1,4)[:,None]`:

```
In [40]: my_func(arr)
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]]
Out[40]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  4,  9],
       [ 0,  1,  8, 27]])
```

Note the whole 2d array is passed.  The `x**k` step works by `broadcasting`, using a (4,) array with a (3,1), to produce a (3,4) result.  You should, if possible write functions that work like this, taking full advantage of the `numpy` methods and operators.

`apply...` can be used as here:

```
In [41]: np.apply_along_axis(my_func, 1, arr)
[1]
[2]
[3]
Out[41]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  4,  9],
       [ 0,  1,  8, 27]])
```

Note that it passes (1,) arrays to the function.  The docs should make it clear that this is designed to pass a 1d array to the function, NOT a scalar.

The equivalent for a 2d `arr` array is:

```
In [42]: np.array([my_func(i) for i in arr])
[1]
[2]
[3]
Out[42]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  4,  9],
       [ 0,  1,  8, 27]])
```

Now lets comment out the `print` and do some time tests:

```
In [44]: timeit my_func(arr)
7.41 µs ± 6.75 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
In [45]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(my_func, 1, arr)
89.2 µs ± 649 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
In [46]: timeit np.array([my_func(i) for i in arr])
28.9 µs ± 1.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

The broadcasted approach is fastest. `apply_along_axis` is slowest.

I claim that `apply_along_axis` is only useful when the array dimensions are greater than 2, and even then it just makes the code prettier, not faster.

For example with a 3d array, that still broadcasts with the (4,) shape `x`:

```
In [47]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [49]: np.apply_along_axis(my_func, 2, arr).shape
Out[49]: (2, 3, 4)
In [50]: my_func(arr).shape
Out[50]: (2, 3, 4)
In [51]: np.array([[my_func(arr[i,j,:]) for j in range(3)] for i in range(2)]).shape
Out[51]: (2, 3, 4)
```

The list iteration requires a double loop.  `apply_along_axis` hides this, but does not reduce the total number of calls to `my_func`.

If your function really required a scalar (e.g. use a `math.cos` or `if` test), then you might consider `np.vectorize`.  For smallist examples it's slower than the equivalent list comprehension, but it does scale better for large ones.  But again, if you can write the function to work directly with array, you'll much happier with the performance.

Comment: I won't say much so that don't say something wrong again, but thank you for clarifications! 1d arrays longer than 1 element will be my next step.